# select column names from table 2, and for this column names, set all the values to 0 from table1

Tags: sql, mysql

Edit:

I have a table: Say TABLE1, and this is the data:

```
--------------------------
COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4
--------------------------
 1   |  10  | 100  | 1000
 1   |  10  | 100  | 1000
 1   |  10  | 100  | 1000
--------------------------
```

and say TABLE2,

```
---------------------------
ID | COL_NAMES
---------------------------
1  | COL3
2  | COL4
---------------------------
```

Now what I want do is select column names from table 2, and for this column names, set all the values to 0 from table1,
This should be end result:

```
--------------------------
COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4
--------------------------
 1   |  10  |   0  |    0
 1   |  10  |   0  |    0
 1   |  10  |   0  |    0
--------------------------
```

How do I write the query?

Comment: can you post your actual code here?

Comment: Change `update table Table1` to `update Table1`. And post your actual code, some data and the required result.

Comment: what you wanted to select in select some code

Comment: @nlx.. which column you need to update?

Comment: edited the post. let me know if you need any more info

Comment: Do you want an update query or select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to `SELECT` on `Table1` you can do something like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT('SELECT ', GROUP_CONCAT(c.COLUMN_NAME),',',
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(0,' as ',t2.COL_NAMES) FROM table2 t2),' FROM table1;')
INTO @query
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
WHERE c.TABLE_NAME = 'table1'
AND c.COLUMN_NAME not in (select COL_NAMES from table2)
ORDER BY c.ORDINAL_POSITION;

PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

### [SELECT Query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bb6db/26)

and if you want to update `table1` you can use this query for update it:

```
SELECT CONCAT('UPDATE TABLE1 SET ', GROUP_CONCAT(c.COLUMN_NAME, ' = ', 0) )
INTO @query
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
WHERE c.TABLE_NAME = 'table1'
AND c.COLUMN_NAME in (select COL_NAMES from table2)
ORDER BY c.ORDINAL_POSITION;

PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

### [UPDATE Query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23cd5/2)